# Automatic LED emergency lamp circuit with overcharge protection for 12v lead-acid battery

Tags: transistors, capacitor, transformer, battery-charging

I am a newbie in the field of electronics.So please  help me with my questions. I am trying to implement this circuit below. [image: This is circuit for an emergency lamp]

I have a 9-0-9 centre tapped transformer. Then how to change the circuit for a fullwave rectification. And I want to use a 12v battery. Will this circuit be sufficient for 12v battery for sure?

---

Requirement summary:

- Charge 12V lead acid battery. Low charging rate is acceptable.
- Maintain 12V lead acid battery at correct "float" voltage when charged.
- Automatically turn on an output (light, LED strip etc) when input power is removed.
- Utilise available 9-0-9Volt output transformer.

Comment: What charging current do you need? What size and technology of battery?

Comment: 12.6 lead acid battery.i need slow charging for emergency lamp. I am using 7 AH battery. No problem if it takes a week to charge completely

Comment: See added circuits. EXAMPLES ONLY. If you are serious about this application we can discuss a better version. Try and understand these circuits as a starting point. | For interest - where are you located?

Comment: Use Maxthon's circuit as input to mine. His U1 is my whole circuit. His cct is the "18 VAC + bridge rectifier " shown in mine.

Comment: I am from India. @RussellMcMahon

Comment: A number of people who have commented have failed to realise that the original circuit is intended to automatically turn on a light when input power fails. The bulb is NOT a charging complete indicator and not a spurious load - it is the intended load with no power input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User requirements

- Charge 12V lead acid battery.
- Maintain 12V lead acid battery at correct "float" voltage when charged.
- Automatically turn on an output (light, LED triop etc) when input power is removed.

---

If you use your 9-0-9 transformer as a single 18V winding it will do what you want. There will be more than enough voltage.

Below is a lead acid battery charger circuit found in very similar form "all over the web". That does not make it good :-) - but its easy and cheapish and works reasonably well.
P1 is used to set Vout to 13.7V. A 12V battery should "float" at 13.7V - NOT higher in standby use.

Q1, R4, R1 are used to set maximum current. R1 = 600 / I_mA Ohms.

[image]

---

Here I have roughly connected the charger to your circuit.
This is **AN EXAMPLE CIRCUIT ONLY**.
We can do better than this. Look at the circuit and understand what it does.
Note that a suitable MOSFET will be better than the 2N3055 here.

Could you build this circuit or similar?
Can you obtain the LM317?
Is this affordable for you?

### EXAMPLE CIRCUIT ONLY - **DISCUSS**

[image]

When there is input power Ra turns the BC557 off and the lamp does not light.
When input power is absent Rb turns the BC557 ann which turns Q1 on which turns the light on.  A 12V LED light would be preferred.
Rc is used to provide "drive" for Q1. For the transistor shown it will need to be in the 100 Ohm- 1K range depending on load. With a suitable MOSFET Rc = 1k.

---

Added:

The battery will automatically stabilise at 13.7V due to internal chemical processes which cause the cell potential to rise as it is charged. Note that this is true for lead acid but **NOT** true for eg LiIon - do this with LiIon and you will damage it.

An LM317 works by increasing its output voltage until the voltage across R3 is 1.25V. Trace the current through R3, see that it flows in R2 + P1. | Set R2 + p1 to 1200 Ohms total. What voltage appears across (R2+P1)?
Say R2 + P1 = R$.

Vout  (R4 + R3) / R3 x 1.25V

Comment: ACK! NO! That's a very bad circuit. At the very least, if the power fails it will drain the battery. Not only that, most of it doesn't do anything. Find another circuit to play with.

Comment: The 18VAC input is "a start" but you need a better charger circuit . With 100R Icharge will be ~~ (Vpkin-Vbat)/100 ~= 100 mA. POwer in R will be ~~~= 1 Watt. But battery will always charge. 100 mA/7AH = C/70 = Maybe OK.

Comment: This is to be placed in mains supply for ever. So always charging is not a problem. But can u please suggest any modification such that it will not overcharge@RussellMcMahon

Comment: I think I am taking too much time to understand the circuit. Thank you very much for the suggestion. I am defenitly going to make this. I can obtain an LM317. But I want to use the 2n3055 itself because i baught it along with heatsink for a higher price. Is there any damage possible to battery if I do not set current limit. And I cannot understand the working of 1k mosfet here. How to connect the mosfet in this circuit.How the charging will be stopped after getting fully charged@RussellMcMahon

Comment: @Russell McMahon: Regarding your 2nd circuit - I think tht diode Da is in the wrong spot.  It should be located between R3 & Battery (+).  Two problems with where it is now: the diode drop between the LM317 & the divider network messes things up *and* the very low resistance of the divider network discharges the battery when AC power is removed.  FWIW: R2 is too low - 1k2 is closer to the correct value.

Comment: @DwayneReid The diode was an afterthought as I was being called away to do other urgent things, and in fact neither location is a good one :-(. I was thinking in terms of a SMPS IC with a reference pin where you want to divide the actual Vout - so Da would be fine. As is it is fatally flawed as you note. But if between R3 and V+ it takes Vdiode off V_LM317 and the 13.7V needed is crucial to proper lead acid float :-(. A few tenths of a volt either way can have significant effect. Use of an opamp and reference diode would be better. I threw it in last thing to protect the 317 against reverse...

Comment: ... voltage when power in failed but a reverse diode across the 317 and may suffice. Have to check. Te input bridge stops transformer back feed.  | R3 R2 P1 forms a load on battery (about 15 mA) but as the aim is to turn on a substantial lighting load when input fails this is bearable.  || Correct on R2 - I copied this from a 6V version and did not change that - as noted EXAMPLE CIRCUIT - no excuses intended but the idea was to see how the degree of complexity and cost sat with Sudheesh. I'd hope for something a bit better overall. MOSFET out nicerbut he has a 2N3055 already. ...

Comment: @SudheeshKs MOSFET would connect where 3055 is now base-> gate, collector->drain. emitter-> source. | Charging stops when Vbattery reaches 13.7V - this is a precise value related to lead acid chemistry. |Do not include diode Da - just short between ends.  | For best life lead acid best charged not too fast. Say C/10 = here 7Ah/10 = 700 mA max. Less OK. | R1 = 600/700 mA ~~= 1 Ohm. Say 1 watt rated.

Comment: First of all thank you everybody. All of you here  have very good helping mind.I will short diode Da.Do I need to change value of R2. I am not worried about a 15mA load. The led light should light up whenever the power supply fails.What simulation tool works best on linux.I dont want to replace 2n3055 if there isnt any significant problem. I love my 2n3055. I understand how the charging current and output voltage are controlled.Can you please explain how charging stops when battery is fully charged and the working of LM317 in a basic level@RussellMcMahon

Comment: @SudheeshKs As per my note - you use P2 to set Vout to 13.7V. The combination of R2 + P1 help set Vout - they need to be higher for 12V. If P1 is say 1K you'll be able to set Vout as high as ~ 16.5V so 13.7V is in that range.

Comment: BC140 is not available. Can I use BD140 or BD 139 instead@RussellMcMahon

Comment: It **MUST** be NPN so BD139 would be OK. (But **NOT** BD140 which is PNP). | **BUT** the BD139 is OK if you have one already BUT it is much larger than is needed. A small cheap "TO92" plastic package NPN transistor will do. | I use BC337-40 for such things but any BC337, 

[**Anything cheap on this list probably**](http://bit.ly/1Dxlxof).

Comment: From that list, examples only:  BC337, BC546, BC547, 2N3904, 2N2222, 2N5088, MPSA05,.... .... many many more. - Small **NPN** plastic cheap

Comment: I dont have bd139 but bd140. And in the mean time I found from some sources that NTE128 is equilant to bc140. So I am planning to buy that or anything from the list as per the availability in the store

Comment: @SudheeshKs OK - note again  **NOT BD140** BUT your "some sources" are wrong as NTE128 is NOT = BD140 | BD139 = NPN = OK. NTE128 = NPN = OK. [NTE129 = PNP = no good. ] BUT NTE12x are old metal can TO66 - big and expensive. Use small plastic TO92.

Comment: OK I got bd139 and 2n2222. But for the  2n2222 local shop gave me ksp2222a. Is it same as 2n2222?. However i have bd139 in hand. Which one shoul I use. I think its all set to do the actual circuit@RussellMcMahon

Comment: @SudheeshKs - As above - the transistor is very non critical. It needs to be NPN. **If you have a BD139 and do not have a 2N2222 etc then the BD139 is OK**. If you have both then the smaller cheaper 2N2222 is OK.

Comment: I have 2.6 ohm resistors and some 2n4007 diodes with me. Can i use a diode in series to the led series connection to reduce input voltage by 0.6v such that i can adjust the required resistor value to 2.6R?@RussellMcMahon

Comment: @SudheeshKs **You should ask this as a new question**. In question give as much information as possible. You also need to specify run time wanted, LED brand/model/data sheet reference if available. Is this powered by a lead acid battery? How do you stop operation if voltage falls too low?  What is the overall application? ...

Comment: I used R2 220R and P1 1k. Its only giving max 11.9v as output of the charging circuit(P1 set to minimum) and min 3.7v(P1 set to max).I have connected trimmer potentiometer as pin 3 as input and pins 1 and 2 shorted as output to neutral line.Is that ok? Also when there is AC mains supply(battery present), light doesnt go off. It glows bright. Also if there is only AC mains and no battery then also bulb is glowing with a dimmed light.Battery only, its glowing bright.When there is AC current base to emitter voltage of 2n3055 is 0.6v. Also what is the purpose of Ra in the circuit@RussellMcMahon

Comment: Voltage INCREASES as P1 INCREASES so if P1 is minimum then voltage is minimum. (R2 + P1_max) need to be > 1.2K. You can use a larger R2 if desired if Vout is too low with P1 at max. | Set Vout to 13.7V with no battery and no lamp or load. Then it should charge to 13.7V max. | Have you provided Ra as shown? That is what turns the light off when DC input is provided. With DCin - Vin is 2V+ higher than Vbattery due to LM317 minimum drop. Ra pulls BC557 base +ve above vbattery so BC557 is off. Without Ra and the series 1N4148 the circuit will not turn off with DC in.

Comment: Re "Also if there is only AC mains and no battery then also bulb is glowing with a dimmed light" --> Cct opn is not designed for Vin and no battery. If this is required then you need to specify what should happen (but why do you want it? It may complicate circuit).

Comment: I have done the circuit exactly as in the figure. Only change I made is replacing 470R with 220R and p1 with 1k potetiometer. I have included 1k Ra as in figure. But I am not getting sufficient voltage.I dont want no battery direct AC option. I think the automatic light switching off circuit is not working properly. How can I check if I have damaged any of transistors due to overheating while soldering@RussellMcMahon

Answer (score 1):

You can use your 9-0-9 transformer as a single 18V winding, leaving the center tap unconnected. Then the full wave rectification part can be done using a bridge rectifier (4 diodes instead of 2) like this. `1N5822` is a jellybean Schottky rectifier diode you can use in your designs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxOGOF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for making the idea crystal clear.My question is resolved. I had doubts about the bridge connection voltage. Thanks a lot @Maxthon Chan

Comment: And i think i can use 1n4007 diode instead of this 1n5822

Answer (score 0):

Your 9-0-9 transformer is specified in RMS, assuming nominal input voltage (this varies too, and the output will follow).  Ignoring that for now, 9Vrms * sqrt(2) = 12.7Vpeak for a sinewave.  When you run it through a rectifier, you get the peak, not RMS.  This alone might answer your initial question.

However, relying on the exact specified output voltage of a mains power transformer is generally a bad idea, simply because the mains will vary and the transformer is only a ratio, not a specific number.  To do this right, you'll want a higher voltage than needed from the transformer (18Vrms/25.4Vpeak in your case; x-0-y means x+y across the entire winding), and then regulate it down from there.

Your original circuit is not a regulator, just a "charge done" indicator.  Once the light is on, it will continue to charge until you unplug it, although more slowly because the light bulb steals some of the current.

Comment: AaronD - Note that his circuit is NOT a 'charge done indicator' - it is a significant lighting load (25 Watts in original!) designed to turn on when input power is removed.

Comment: Oh, okay.  I must have missed that somewhere.  I see you've edited the question to clarify.  Somehow I was thinking that the BC557 would turn on when it's done, but a second look shows that I was wrong.  If it was called an emergency light or something like that, I might have caught on sooner.  Oh well.